# ActivityNotFoundException exception but source is not error on android

Tags: android

I want apk url download

I try this code

```
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https:/~~~~.apk"),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

but this code ActivityNotFoundException .

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://~~~~~.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
>                                                                                           at company.co.kr.installupdate2016_0421.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Perhaps, url problem?
 thanks

Comment: i dont think you can put url in this method

Comment: problem in here `setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https:/~~~~.apk")`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  I know but how do I modify  , I don't know

Answer (score 1):

The url you have provided is wrong :) Proper url would be  https://~~~~.apk :)and you have provided https:/~~~~.apk :) Thats not proper url scheme :)

So please modify your code as :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://~~~~.apk"),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

**EDIT**

The code above will work only if you have playstore or anyother app which opts for capturing the thrown intent :)

If you are running it on rooted device without playstore or on simulator without playstore it will crash as you have posted in question :)

As you have mentioned, you want to install it without playstore :) here is what you can do :)

Download the apk programmatically :) save it and then throw intent as shown below :) can be one of the solution :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile("your_apk_file_location), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

And everything should be fine :D Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: thanks , but your advice code for me what change code?

Comment: url scheme buddy :) url schemes have two forward slashes :) not one :) you have written https:/~~~~.apk it is wrong url scheme :) proper url scheme is https://~~~~.apk :) can you see 2 "/" ?? thats it :)

Comment: Are you running it on simulator or any device which does not have play store installed buddy ???

Comment: ah.. perhaps  this url install code  have playstore? I want install without market

Comment: :D You are throwing an intent buddy :) which means you are asking android OS is there any app which can handle the task of downloading and installing app for me from this url :D So there should be some application which does that task for you in your device :) like playstore or anything else (Sorry am not aware of anything else then playstore which does this task). Because you have said you dont have play store android is throwing you the exception :)

Comment: I try `   Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(apkfile);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }`

Comment: Did you download the apk ?? saved it in your local device's internal or external memory ??? Are you providing local file path to Uri.fromFile ?? What is the exception you are getting ???